Why doesn't 'profile/<int:pk>' work in django
I'm new to django. I have a problem with profiles. When I open the main page or others I get knocked out in error:
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['registration/profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\Z']

I do not know what to do with it. Boom is very grateful for the help!
here is the code:
models.py:
import os.path
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class reg(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField('email', max_length=50)
    password1 = models.CharField('password1', max_length=20)
    password2 = models.TextField('password2')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'registration'
        verbose_name_plural = 'registration'


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, verbose_name='user', related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images', default='media/default.jpg', blank=True)

urls.py:
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ProfileView
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),  # Remove leading slash from '/register'
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

views.py:
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from .models import UserProfile


def register(request):  # Change function name to match the URL pattern
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f'Аккаунт создан!')
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    form = RegistrationForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})


class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/user_profile.html')


class ProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user = profile.user

        context = {
            'user': user,
            'profile': profile,
        }
        return render(request, 'registration/user_profile.html', context)

layout.html(the error occurs in layout.html!):
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <script src="{% static 'fontawesomefree/js/all.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <img src="{% static 'main/img/LS_logo_BW.png' %}" alt="Beta Logo">
        <span class="logo">Loping</span>
        <h3>Навигация</h3>
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
  </ul>
        <ul>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-house-chimney"></i> Главная</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'about' %}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i> О нас</li></a>
            <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i> Контакты</li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'news' %}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li> <i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i> Новости</li></a>
            {% if user.is_staff %}
                <a href="/admin" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i> Панель админа</li></a>
            {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'create' %}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Добавить запись</button></li></a>
            <a href="{% url 'register' %}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Создать аккаунт</button></li></a>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="{% url 'logout'%}?next={{request.path}}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></i> Выйти из аккаунта</button></li></a>
                <a href="{% url 'profile' user.profile.id %}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></i> Профиль</button></li></a>
                <li>Вы вошли как: {{ user.get_username }}</li>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'login'%}?next={{request.path}}" style="text-decoration: none;"><li><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i> Войти в аккаунт</button></li></a>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>
</body>
</html>

user_profile.html:
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'profile/css/profile.css'%}">
<div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="features">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ profile.picture.url }}" style="border-radius: 50%" height="150px" width="150px" />
        {% if profile.name %}
        <h3 class="py-4">{{ profile.name }}</h3>
        {% endif %}

        {% if profile.location %}
        <h3 class="py-4">{{ profile.location }}</h3>
        {% endif %}

        {% if profile.birth_date %}
        <h3 class="py-4">{{ profile.birth_date }}</h3>
        {% endif %}

        {% if profile.bio %}
        <h3 class="py-4">{{ profile.bio }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

I've tried videos and articles from the Internet. Nothing is working

error may suggests that it tries to access profile/ without number. And this can make problem because 'profile/<int:pk>' expects number. You have to find in your HTML where you have url with profile/ without number  and check why you generate this url without number.

I think problem can be in return redirect('profile') and in def profile(request): because they don't use number

I tried to do this with the number, but it still doesn't work.

all because you may have mistakes in few places - like return redirect('profile') and in def profile(request): - they may need return redirect('profile/<some_number>') and in def profile(request, number):

it looks also strange that you have def profile(...) and class ProfileView

Why? What's wrong with them

Rycm unfortunately your method does not work

Did my answer work ? What's the error message ?

the same error is NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(",)' not found. 1 template(s) tried: ['registration/profile/(?P[0-9]+)\Z'] in the file layout.html . Here:  Profile

Show us your project urls.py file.

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('main.urls')),
path('news/', include('news.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),  # Include default auth URLs
path('registration/', include("registration.urls")),  # Include your custom registration URLs
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Try "{% url 'profile' user.id %}.

Obviously, profile object isn't created yet just after registering; to access profile.id. That's why.

1) user_id

'profile/int:pk

need a number.
But you redirect to  return redirect('profile').
2) absolute path
You need to redirect to the absolute path. Otherwise, it's going to redirect to the relative path registration/profile. Which is not a valid pattern.
Try below.

Part


return redirect(f'/profile/{user.id}')

#Or

return redirect(f'/profile/{request.user.id}')



Part

Try {% url 'profile' user.id %}.
